# Join or group two models together that share a polymorphic relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've built a reports system where users can report posts or comments to be moderated that have violated the rules of the site.

I would like to query both the comment and post reports together and group the reports together under the comment or post they belong to. Then I want organize by the post or comments `created_at` fields.

## Tables

**Posts**

- id (int)
- content ( text)
- title (text)
- created_at

**Comment**

- id (int)
- content (int)
- post_id (int)
- created_at

**Report**

- id (int)
- user_id (int)
- content (text)
- reportable_id (int)
- reportable_type (string)

**User**

- id (int)
- name (string)

## Relations

**Post.php**

```php
public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
}
```

**Comment.php**

```php
public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
}
```

**Report.php**

```php
public function reportable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

## What I would like to do

I want to organize reports in 3 separate ways.

**1.** Get all posts with reports and the users that made the report and organize by latest.

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user', 'comments')->latest()->get();
```

Output:

**This is a post from 1 day ago**

- Report 1 about comment by user 1
- Report 2 about comment by user 4

**This is a post from 3 days ago**

- Report 1 by user 3
- Report 2 by user 5

**2.** Get all comments with reports, the users that made the report, the post the comment is under and organize by latest.

```php
$comments  = Comment::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user', 'post')->latest()->get();
```

*This is a post from 1 day ago*

**A nasty comment on a post by user 10**

- Report 1 by user 1
- Report 2 by user 4

*This is a post from 3 days ago*

**Another nasty comment on a post by user 15**

- Report 1 by user 3
- Report 2 by user 5

**3.** Here is where I'm having trouble. I would like to organize `Post` and `Comment` Reports together and maintain grouping the reports under the model like above. Example:

**This is a post from 1 day ago**

- Report 1 about comment by user 1
- Report 2 about comment by user 4

*This is a post from 1 day ago*

**A nasty comment on a post by user 10**

- Report 1 by user 1
- Report 2 by user 4

**This is a post from 3 days ago**

- Report 1 by user 3
- Report 2 by user 5

*This is a post from 3 days ago*

**Another nasty comment on a post by user 15**

- Report 1 by user 3
- Report 2 by user 5

Here is my attempt at trying to get both `Post` and `Comment` reports together:

```php
$reports = Report::with('reportable')->latest()->get();
//return view('reports.index', compact('posts'));
```

**Output**

```json
"7": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "user_id": 2,
        "content": "Guy is being a jerk",
        "reportable_id": 7,
        "reportable_type": "App\\Post",
        "created_at": "2017-08-22 01:31:25",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-22 01:31:25",
        "is_handled": 0,
        "reportable": {
            "id": 7,
            "author_id": 1,
            "category_id": null,
            "title": "A forum post!",
            "created_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "user_id": 2,
        "content": "this guy is being rude",
        "reportable_id": 7,
        "reportable_type": "App\\Post",
        "created_at": "2017-08-22 01:31:02",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-22 01:31:02",
        "is_handled": 0,
        "reportable": {
            "id": 7,
            "author_id": 1,
            "category_id": null,
            "title": "A forum post!",
            "created_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 1,
        "content": "Report number 1",
        "reportable_id": 7,
        "reportable_type": "App\\Post",
        "created_at": "2017-08-21 20:40:55",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-21 20:40:55",
        "is_handled": 0,
        "reportable": {
            "id": 7,
            "author_id": 1,
            "title": "A forum post!",
            "created_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22"
        }
    }
],
"9": [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "user_id": 4,
        "content": "Rule 1",
        "reportable_id": 9,
        "reportable_type": "App\\Post",
        "created_at": "2017-09-20 21:31:50",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-20 21:31:50",
        "is_handled": 0,
        "reportable": {
            "id": 9,
            "author_id": 1,
            "title": "Hello world!",
            "created_at": "2017-09-10 16:49:07",
            "updated_at": "2017-09-10 16:49:07",
        }
    }
],
"24": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "user_id": 4,
        "content": "Rule 2",
        "reportable_id": 24,
        "reportable_type": "App\\Comment",
        "created_at": "2017-09-20 22:28:15",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-21 03:03:28",
        "is_handled": 1,
        "reportable": {
            "id": 24,
            "user_id": 1,
            "content": "<p>A comment to be edited</p>",
            "created_at": "2017-09-17 22:41:35",
            "updated_at": "2017-09-17 22:41:35",
            "commentable_id": 9,
            "commentable_type": "App\\Forum"
        }
    }
]
```

The problems I'm having is formatting the report right, pagination, and organizing the reports by the `Comment` and `Post` `created_at` date. Is there a way just to just query the `Post`, `Comments`, `User`, and `Reports` Model all together to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I'm really sorry for such a long post.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to format this would be to use instead of a `morphMany()` is a [hasMany()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow as to why and what would the code look like for the query I'm trying to create?

Comment: return $this->hasMany(‘App\Reports’)

Comment: How would query both Comments and Posts Reports at the same time using many to many relationships?